# If $f\left( x\right) =x^{2}+x-3$, prove that $\lim _{x\rightarrow 1}f\left( x\right) =-1$.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

Proof. Let $\varepsilon >0$ and set $L=-1$. Notice that $f\left( x\right) -L=x^{2}+x-2=\left( x-1\right) \left( x+2\right)$.

If $0 < \delta < 1$, then $\left| x-1\right| < \delta$ implies $0<x<2$, so by the triangle inequality, $\left| x+z\right| \leq \left| x\right| +2 < 4$. Set $\delta =\min \left\{ 1,\varepsilon / 4\right\}$. It follows that if $\left| x-1\right| < \delta$, then

$\left| f\left( x\right) -L\right| =\left| x-1\right| \left| x+2\right|<4\left| x-1\right| < 4\delta \leq \varepsilon$.

**My question is:** I couldn't understand these sentences '' If $0 < \delta < 1$, then $\left| x-1\right| < \delta$ implies $0<x<2$, so by the triangle inequality, $\left| x+2\right| \leq \left| x\right| +2 < 4$. Set $\delta =\min \left\{ 1,\varepsilon / 4\right\}$''. Why $0 < \delta < 1$? How $0<x<2$? What is the $\delta =\min \left\{ 1,\varepsilon / 4\right\}$ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} f(x)=-1$ you need that $\forall\varepsilon>0~\exists\delta>0:~|x-1|<\delta~\Rightarrow~ |f(x)-(-1)|<\varepsilon$.

For $0<\delta<1$ you can rewrite the inequality $|x-1|<\delta$ as $-\delta<x-1<\delta$ and therefore you get $$-(1)+1<-\delta+1<x<\delta+1<1+1=2$$
Now you can use the triangle inequality. (Note that you can only ensure that the inequality $0<x<2$ is correct if $\delta<1$.)

$\delta=\min\{1,\frac{\varepsilon}{4}\}$ means that (depending on $\varepsilon$) $\delta$ is either 1 or $\frac{\varepsilon}{4}$, whichever is smaller. If $\varepsilon=5$ for example it would be $\delta=1$ because $1<\frac{5}{4}$. If $\varepsilon=3$ it would be $\delta=\frac{3}{4}$ because $\frac{3}{4}<1$.

You do this so that in any case you can use the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 2):

If $|x-1|<\delta$, then $x-1$ is between $-\delta$ and $\delta$ so $x$ is between $1-\delta$ and $1+\delta$.  In particular, if $0<\delta<1$, that will guarantee that $0<1-\delta<x<1+\delta<2$, so $0<x<2$.

(Note, however, that when it says $0<\delta<1$, it should really say $0<\delta\leq 1$ instead.  This does not affect the validity of the paragraph above since you still have $0\leq 1-\delta<x<1+\delta\leq 2$ giving $0<x<2$, but you need it since when you define $\delta=\min\{1,\epsilon/4\}$ as explained below, that might mean that $\delta=1$ instead of $\delta<1$.)

When it says "Set $\delta=\min\{1,\epsilon/4\}$", that means you should define $\delta$ to be the smaller of the two numbers $1$ and $\epsilon/4$.  Note that in this argument you are given $\epsilon$ and want to find $\delta$ such that a certain condition holds, so you get to decide how you want to define $\delta$ using $\epsilon$, and that is what this line is doing.

This choice of $\delta$ is made because it is what you need in order for the final step of proof to work.  You need to know that if $|x-1|<\delta$ then $|x+2|<4$, which has been proven under the assumption that $0<\delta\leq 1$, so you need to be sure $\delta\leq 1$.  You also need to know that $4\delta\leq \epsilon$, or $\delta\leq \epsilon/4$.  So defining $\delta$ to be the smaller of $1$ and $\epsilon/4$ guarantees both of these statements are true (and also guarantees that $\delta>0$ since both $1$ and $\epsilon/4$ are positive).

Comment: Thanks. So, why not ''set $\delta =min\left\{ 0,\varepsilon / 4\right\}$?

Comment: Also, why we should  define $\delta$ to be smaller of the ''two numbers''? Why not three or four etc. numbers?

Comment: I have added some explanation of the motivation for this choice of $\delta$.